# Running django site and wikis on the same linux machine with apache

Tags: django, apache, wiki, virtualhost

I've got a bit of a problem with forcing django based site and a "regular" sites i.e. wikis to work on the same machine, and to top it I'm kinda new to this stuff...

I've been trying to setup this using the VirtualHost but it seems that this does not work very well. In other words I can either run the django site (alredy in form of **host.com/djangosite**) and other sites in the same time (i.e **host.com/othersite1**). Only one works at a time it looks like the apache runs first VirtualHost it finds.

the structure in the server looks like this

```
/var/www/djangosite
/var/www/othersite1
/var/www/othersite2 ... etc
```

Now the sites-enabled, I experimented a bit and finally ended up in one file with two VirtualHosts for now:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ss@dd.gg
        DocumentRoot /var/www/djangosite
        ServerName host.com/djangosite

        Alias /m/ "/var/www/djangosite/forum/skins/"
        <Directory "/var/www/djangosite/forum/skins">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /upfiles/ "/var/www/djangosite/forum/upfiles/"
        <Directory "/var/www/djangosite/forum/upfiles">
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias /djangosite /var/www/djangosite/djangosite.wsgi

        CustomLog /var/log/djangosite.access.log common
        ErrorLog /var/log/djangosite.error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/othersite1
        ServerName host.com/othersite1
</VirtualHost>
```

On their own both VirtualHosts do ok, i.e. when I put this in a file in sites-enabled the djangosite works fine, the second is not found, (something with document root being rooted at wrong dir in filesystem structure). If I put the second Vhost on top it works the djangosite doesn't.

Ok. so now a real question is there a recipe for running djangosite and "regular" site on one linux/apache configuration with one NIC and one hostname.

thanks for at least reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two seperate VirtualHosts. Just put them both in the same one, with the ServerName as just "host.com". Then you can use aliases - the WSGIScriptAlias for the Django site, and a normal Alias for the wiki.

One note: please do not put your Django code in the DocumentRoot. This is dangerous - it makes it potentially possible for people to see your code, including your passwords etc in settings.py. Move it somewhere else, and leave out the DocumentRoot directive.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try in a few moments.

Comment: Ok It works like a charm :) thank you I though it should be something simple :)